# Python Script to Replace text in template file with value from a list

Tags: python, list, text, replace

This is probobly a blink of an eye to most of you but I am learning.

I am editing multiple web pages and want to edit one line at the top and insert a value into it with an item in a list.

Then move onto the next item in the list and edit the template file with this item and move onto the next one.  I have read for a few hours on here now but cannot find a solution.  Please can someone help.

Currently have a file structure of:
websitetemplate.asp (there is a line at the top with "SKU" in it which is the portion to edit.
sku_list.txt (this has multiple values which I want to insert into the template and save each one.

Comment: I am helping you.  Not that hard.  If you use UNIX I can give you one short command to do that

Comment: are you using windows or linux?

Comment: Using windows 10 but have access to UNIX. I was hoping to use Python if possible because I am trying to teach myself it.

Comment: You can combine UNIX commands with python. Just try :

Comment: du -a | awk '{print $2}' | grep '\.html$' can return all your html files. with python you can make a list of all your files and use ed to append that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick python solution:

```py
with open('sku_list.txt', 'r') as skusfile:
    for sku in skusfile.read().split('\n'):
        with open("websitetemplate.asp", 'r') as templatefile:
            template = templatefile.read()
        with open(f"{sku}.asp", 'w+') as writefile:
            writefile.write(template.replace('[replacekeyword]', sku))
```

It opens your list and splits it by newlines (insert whatever operator you have inbetween).

Then it opens the website template and saves it in the `template` variable.

Last, you replace whatever replacekeyword you have with the different values in the skulist and write them each to their own file.

Comment: Thank you for this. The output is close to what I am after - it creates the new files names as the SKU but it doesn't change the value SKU within the file - does that make sense?

Comment: If it is what you were looking for, please accept the answer :)

Comment: How can I edit the string in 'website template' which is current reads 'SKU' with the same value as the name for that page?  Otherwise I have lots of different named pages but they will all be identical.

Comment: You replace [replacekeyword] with SKU

Comment: `writefile.write(template.replace('SKU', sku))`

Comment: I've done that.  It still isn't editing the text within the file it's creating.

Comment: <%
  displaytitle = "sku" 
 productname = displaytitle 
%> is the output within the file whereas sku needs to be populated with the same ref as the file name.

Comment: then you need to put sku, not SKU. You tell the function what it should search and replace

Comment: Perfect - thanks. Although it's now replacing it once I am getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/A/Desktop/worlddesktoppagescript/WorldURL.py", line 5, in <module>
    with open(f"{sku}.asp", 'w+') as writefile:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\n30966.asp'
>>>

Comment: you might wanna remove the \n from the filename, the OS doesn't like that